# Do Android Cursor/ContentProvider have intrinsic race condition between query and notifyChanged?

Tags: android, multithreading, cursor, android-contentprovider

My UI view needs to display some content and keep it updated. I plan on using standard Cursor/ContentProvider framework. Still, I cannot figure out, if there can be a race condition here:

- A content provider creates a new *Cursor* with data A in implementation of method *ContentProvider#query*.
- While the method *query* is finishing, *another* thread of the same provider updates data state to value B. It properly notifies world about it, calling *ContentResolver#notifyChanged*. Since content provider is inherently multi-threaded, this seems quite probable.
- Then client application receives (or could receive) the change notification, but it doesn't listen to it, since it hasn't received the *Cursor* yet and so didn't register a *ContentObserver*.
- The *Cursor* with obsolete data is finally passed to binder and then it reaches client application. Client application has no clue that the data is obsolete.

Could you please advise, if this problem is imaginary or there is actual possibility of loosing data?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an imaginary issue. I have experimental and undertested, but promising solution in form of custom `CursorWrapper` you can return from `ContentProvider.query()`. The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/chalup/4201307da02b9cfe4f40).

Besides fixing your issue, it also allows you to set multiple notification Uris on a single Cursor - useful if the query returning this Cursor JOINs multiple tables.